# Why am I getting an importing error for tkinter with the code below?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a newby to python and am struggling with the basic code below. I am uncertain why I am not getting a Tk window to open. The code I have thus far is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import tkk 

class Application(tk.Tk):
    """Application root window"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

**The error I receive back from my terminal is:**

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'tkk' from 'tkinter'
(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you doing "from tkinter import tkk". The first line should be all you need.

Comment: What's `tkk` supposed to be?  Do you perhaps mean `ttk`?

Comment: `import tkinter.ttk` shoud work, its `ttk` and not `tkk` or `from tkinter import ttk`

Comment: The error is telling you precisely what is wrong. There is nothing in the tkinter module named tkk.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out instead: `from tkinter import ttk`.

Comment: +1 Very good first answer (well done and welcome to SO!). For future, it may be helpful to explain that `tkk` is not part of tkinter and that you assume the module the OP (original poster) is after is instead `tkinter.ttk` (which can be imported using `from tkinter import ttk`). For in-line code, use back-ticks (\`) to format it pretty.